# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors

I am getting an error that says Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ActionIcon' does not exist in the current context

but ActionIcon does exist in my current content.

its defined here

```
<input type="image" ID="ActionIcon" class="JSActionIcon" 
      runat="server" Width="13" Height="13" src="image.gif" />
```

I tried changing it into an asp Image like so

```
<asp:Image ID="ActionIcon" CssClass="JSActionIcon" 
     runat="server" ImageUrl="image.gif"/>
```

but that did not work....here is where its complaining that the name 'ActionIcon' does not exist in the current context...

```
<td>&nbsp;
    <span style="text-align:center;">

        <a class="LinkButtonBlueSmall" name="ApproveBtn"
           onclick="ChangeOne('Approve','<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                  Approve</a>

        <a class="LinkButtonOrangeSmall" name="RejectBtn"
           onclick="ChangeOne('Reject', '<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                    Reject</a>

        <a class="LinkButtonMutedSmall" name="ClearBtn"
           onclick="ChangeOne('Clear', '<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                    Clear</a>

     </span>
</td>
```

Anybody got any ideas on why the error is coming up.

I have this inside an ItemTemplate which is inside a ListView, which is inside a ContentTemplate, which is inside a Update Panel.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:asp-classic] tag when you mean [tag:asp.net] - they are very different technologies.

Comment: Sorry about that Oded

Comment: If the id is inside some contentplace holder, or inside some other custom control, then can not find it.

Comment: They are both inside the same ItemTemplate

Comment: So I guess my next question is how do I find the id that is inside a ItemTemplate